# Python - playing video using ffplay displays file in larger resolution

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a simple script that plays a video using ffplay.
The problem I'm running into is that the output file has a larger resolution than it should have.
The resolution of the file to be played is 1280x720, however, when I open the file with ffplay, the output is scaled to 1920x1080.
I even tried to downscale the output by factor 1.5 (to get it to play in 1280x720), but the quality is noticeably worse compared to playing the same file in VLC player.
What am I missing here?

This is the code I'm using:

```
dbFile = "file.mp4"
open_dbFile = "ffplay {0} -window_title {1} -left 50 -top 50 -nostats".format(dbFile, "DB_file")
sub.Popen(open_dbFile)
```

this is the log:

```
ffplay version N-95171-g6ca3d34ff8 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20190918

configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 59.101 / 58. 59.101
  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 59.100 /  7. 59.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100

Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-12-24T15:03:27.000000Z
  Duration: 00:08:36.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 588 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 459 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-24T15:03:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 12/24/2017.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-24T15:03:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 12/24/2017.
   1.59 A-V: -0.014 fd=   0 aq=   19KB vq=   30KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Thanks for your help!
db

Comment: Show the full log from `ffplay` (without `-hide_banner`).

Comment: @ llogan: just edit my post to include the log. Thanks!

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue doing a lazy test on a single file. Does it work as expected if you run the same command in your terminal? Does it do the same thing with another player such as mpv? Does it occur only with a certain file?

Comment: @ llogan: thanks for chiming in. Every video file is upscaled by a factor of 1.5. 
 I also tried to play the file with cv2 and from the command prompt, but the result was the same.  Maybe I should try to run it on a different computer to see if the problem persists.

Comment: I should mention that I'm running Windows 10, and playing the file in VLC (by just double clicking on it) displays the file just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this thing out..
my screen resolution is set to 3840x2160 and the scaling option is set to 150% (Recommended).

[image]

Once I set this option to 100% the output plays in the correct resolution. On the other hand, I'm having a hard time reading any text now unless I use magnifying glasses... ;-)

Cheers!